# Java Applet - multiple .class files

Tags: java, html, applet, embed

I have some annoying problem with java applet.

Basically I made java applet that works fine. After finishing it, i wanted to embed it in html file and that is where my problem began.

When i compiled applet i saw 7 more .class files besides my basic .class file (Game$1.class,Game$2.class,Game$3.class,...,Game$7.class,Game.class)

I tried to ignore the rest of .class files and to embed just Game.class into html but it didn't work. When I tried to run applet it just showed just blank html page.

I tried same html code with simple "Hello world" applet and it worked so I assume that html file is correct

My html file is located in bin folder just as whole java package.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Those are your anonymous inner classes in compiled form. You can't leave them out of the bundle, your applet won't work without them.

Comment: Actually i don't leave them out. All classes (anonymous inner classes and 'normal' class) are in the same folder from very beginning.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, the extra classes are because of anonymous inner classes that are in the code.  They must be on the run-time class-path of the app. for it to function properly.

There are a number of ways to fix to this problem.  Here are 2:

1. Put all the anonymous inner classes in the same `bin` location as the main applet class.
2. Put all classes into one Jar file, put the Jar file in the `bin` dir., mention it in the `archive` attribute of the applet.

---

BTW:  Why is this an applet at all?  What does the browser wrapper bring to the applet (besides challenges)?  If 'nothing', better to launch the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Actually anonymous inner classes were at the same folder as game.class file from the very beginning. Path goes something like this: .../bin/pack/ and in pack folder I have all classes together. So it won't work when i declare game.class in code attribute. I also tried solution with jar file in archive attribute and it won't work also. I just added archive = "game.jar" right next to code attribute and it won't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: *"Any other ideas?"*  1)  **Answer** questions that I ask.  2) Load the applet HTML using [Appleteer](http://pscode.org/appleteer/) & copy/paste what it reports.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the sort of class names you have given it seems you have some inner classes in your class. Can you post the code for Game.java to have better understanding.

Comment: You can get .java file from here alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/~mi09052/Game.java .Basically my problem is how to embed applet in html file when i have anonymous inner classes. All .class files are in the same folder and in code attribute of html file I declare just Game.class and it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem just that, in your `<applet>` tag, you're specifying the URL of the `.class` file directly instead of using a `.jar` file?

In that case, perhaps you should read [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) from the Java Tutorials.

Comment: I also tried with .jar file. I located it in the same folder as my html file and java package folder and it won't work.

Comment: @B.P.: Your `.jar` file contains *all* the `.class` files?  In the correct folder structure? Your HTML references the URL to the `.jar` file, not the URL to any specific `.class` file?  If that's the case, can you elaborate on what you mean by "it won't work"?